# Why won't must flexDirection: 'column' push space between?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have:

```
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.heroGrid}>
          <Typography variant='h3' >
Some stuff
          </Typography>
          <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            here
          </div>

        </Grid>
```

And heroGrid is:

```
    heroGrid: {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'space-between'
    }
```

But it doesn't push my content to be apart.

Comment: flex direction column , requires an height higher than the content to show gap in between flex children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the top level `<Grid>` component is probably being calculated to be exactly the height of the elements it contains.

So, it's pushing all the extra space between the two elements—it just so happens there's 0px of extra space!

You could test this temporarily by setting a fixed height to the `<Grid>` element with something like:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.heroGrid} style={{height: 500}}>
```

If you're elements are then pushed apart as desired, you then need to figure out how you want to actually set the height of the Grid element. If it should fill the parent, you could make the height `100%`. If it should be a fixed height, you could set it to the specific fixed height.